# Facebook iOS SDK - GitHub - Cannot switch back calling app

Tags: facebook

According to the GitHub,

> If the app is running in a version of iOS that supports multitasking, and if the device has the Facebook app of version 3.2.3 or greater installed, the SDK attempts to open the authorization dialog withing the Facebook app. After the user grants or declines the authorization, the Facebook app redirects back to the calling app, passing the authorization token, expiration, and any other parameters the Facebook OAuth server may return.*

My application calls authorize: permissions: delegate: and my application is suspended and Facebook application is launched and authorization is asked. After the user allow or disallow, the Facebook applications stayed on NEWS FEED (not returning to my application).

Questions:

1. Is it possible to authorize or logged-in and returning to my application?
2. How can my application check whether the authorization and logged-in is done and no need to re-do again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this.

*During single sign-on, the Facebook application isn't redirecting back to my application after a user authorizes it. What's wrong?
Make sure you've edited your application's .plist file properly, so that your applicaition binds to the fb[appId]:// URL scheme (where "[appId]" is your Facebook application ID).*

My Application can be switched :)

Thanks all

Comment: I've made sure this step is correct, but the facebook app still won't redirect to my ios app. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: In xcode 4.5.6 you'll need to make the FB part of the URL in upper case or your binary will fail validation: "the following url schemes found in your app are disallowed: [fb]"

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for long time finally got a solution for this problem, I dont its correct but its working like charm for my App:

```
go to developer.facebook.com

Select your app from list (App which app is your are using in URL scheme)

If your app is selected as native app then it will ask for bundle identifiers

provide him bundle identifier by using which you are building your app

if your using wildcard bundle identifier then provide like com.product.abc otherwise provide full bundle identifier.
```

[image]